# iOS Swift AND Xamarin App Crashing using UIImagePickerController/ImagePicker

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xamarin, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm getting a strange issue when taking photos using Swift 3 on an iPhone 6s. I'm trying to take many photos one after the other and eventually the app crashes.

using the following code:

```
import UIKit

class WelcomeViewController : UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate 
{
    var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!
    var photoCount : Int = 0
    @IBOutlet weak var photoCountLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var memoryUseageLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func TakePhotoAction(_ sender: Any) {
        if (imagePicker == nil)
        {
            imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
        }

        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        photoCount = photoCount + 1;

        photoCountLabel.text = String(photoCount)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        photoCount = 0;

    }
}
```

I'm getting an app crash and xcode is saying that it has "lost connection" with the device.
So everything is pointing to a memory leak, and running instruments suggests that, it is also suggesting that there are new threads created over and over and they never finish.

Problem is, I'm using very basic code, reusing the picker, dismissing the view and this is the only view in the entire app.

To make things even more strange, the exception doesn't occur at all when i use my iPhone 7 on iOS 10.3.1, or on another iPhone 6 (not +) with iOS 10.3.2

So i downgraded the 6+ to 10.3.1 and got the exception again. I even put on iOS 11 Beta and the exception still occurred.

I'm hoping someone can at least give me some explanation as to what is going on or why.

**UPDATE**

I was experiencing this on a Xamarin Forms PCL project and decided to strip it all out and write a Swift version to see if the problem still occurred or not. Turns out it did. Anyway, while testing the Xamarin App, we got an exception.

The exception was written to a log file. This is the contents:

```
Error Occurred:
Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: *** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key:         UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage)
Native stack trace:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018a93eff8 <redacted> + 148
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001893a0538 objc_exception_throw + 56
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018a822528 <redacted> + 0
3   PhotoLibrary                        0x0000000197b18980 <redacted> + 756
4   PhotoLibrary                        0x0000000197b1864c PLNotifyImagePickerOfImageAvailability + 28
5   CameraUI                            0x00000001a08e990c <redacted> + 456
6   CameraUI                            0x00000001a08e9218 <redacted> + 548
7   UIKit                               0x0000000190aa5010 <redacted> + 96
8   UIKit                               0x0000000190aa4f90 <redacted> + 80
9   UIKit                               0x0000000190a8f504 <redacted> + 440
10  UIKit                               0x0000000190aa4874 <redacted> + 576
11  UIKit                               0x0000000190aa4390 <redacted> + 2480
12  UIKit                               0x0000000190a9f728 <redacted> + 3192
13  UIKit                               0x0000000190a7033c <redacted> + 340
14  UIKit                               0x000000019126a014 <redacted> + 2400
15  UIKit                               0x0000000191264770 <redacted> + 4268
16  UIKit                               0x0000000191264a50 <redacted> + 5004
17  UIKit                               0x0000000191264a50 <redacted> + 5004
18  UIKit                               0x0000000191264b9c <redacted> + 148
19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018a8ed42c <redacted> + 24
20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018a8ecd04 <redacted> + 388
21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018a8ea9a8 <redacted> + 744
22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018a81ada4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
23  GraphicsServices                    0x000000018c284074 GSEventRunModal + 100
24  UIKit                               0x0000000190ad5058 UIApplicationMain + 208
25  MyApp_iOS_beta                      0x0000000100bcb634 wrapper_managed_to_native_UIKit_UIApplication_UIApplicationMain_int_string___intptr_intptr + 340
26  MyApp_iOS_beta                      0x000000010050c59c UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___intptr_intptr + 44
27  MyApp_iOS_beta                      0x000000010050c45c UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___string_string + 172
28  MyApp_iOS_beta                      0x0000000100078164 MyApp_iOS_Application_Main_string__ + 212
29  MyApp_iOS_beta                      0x00000001011f29f4 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 244
30  MyApp_iOS_beta                      0x00000001038e504c mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 836
31  MyApp_iOS_beta                      0x000000010394f6b4 do_runtime_invoke + 112
32  MyApp_iOS_beta                      0x00000001039522dc do_exec_main_checked + 152
33  MyApp_iOS_beta                      0x00000001038cea44 mono_jit_exec + 268
34  MyApp_iOS_beta                      0x0000000103a02f70 xamarin_main + 2148
35  MyApp_iOS_beta                      0x00000001038a5e84 main + 96
36  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000018982959c <redacted> + 4

Stack Trace:
  at ObjCRuntime.Runtime.ThrowNSException (System.IntPtr ns_exception) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4691/d2270eec/source/xamarin-macios/src/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:319 
  at ObjCRuntime.Runtime.throw_ns_exception (System.IntPtr exc) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4691/d2270eec/source/xamarin-macios/runtime/Delegates.generated.cs:126 
  at (wrapper native-to-managed) ObjCRuntime.Runtime:throw_ns_exception (intptr)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4691/d2270eec/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79 
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4691/d2270eec/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63 
  at MyApp.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00009] in /Users/MyApp/iOS/Main.cs:16
```

Comment: Create a sample app with just image picker code without anything else, have a look onto memory issue there. If sample app works well, the cause of the issue is somewhere around of the code you've provided.

Comment: That's exactly what I've done... this is literally the only view/controlller in the app

Comment: You are presenting the same image picker controller several times, that could be the issue, because image picker can be in invalid state after it has been used once.

Comment: i also tried that, it only seemed to make the issue worse

Answer (score 0):

```
var image: UIImage? = (info.value(forKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage) as? UIImage)
```

Use this key for get the Original Image from Library. In native iOS

This is reference for Xamarin https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/media/video_and_photos/choose_a_photo_from_the_gallery/

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not picking a photo from the library when this happens